# OSX Homebrew : catkin_make_isolated

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When invoking the command

---

$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

---

I get the following output

---

==> Processing plain cmake package: 'stage'

CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
Could NOT find FLTK (missing: FLTK_LIBRARIES FLTK_FLUID_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.0.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindFLTK.cmake:320 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
CMakeLists.txt:105 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/keeholee/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/stage/devel/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'stage':
Command '/Users/keeholee/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/smclib/env.sh cmake /Users/keeholee/ros_catkin_ws/src/stage -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/keeholee/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/stage -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release' returned non-zero exit status 1

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196511/osx-homebrew-:-catkin_make_isolated/) by [itskeeho](https://answers.ros.org/users/20670/itskeeho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install dependencies via rosdep? It appears you are missing FLTK, which is not a ROS package and should be coming in from the rosdep step of the install.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0